# Pop a navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have two views, V1 and V2.  I want to "present" V2 when the add button is pressed on V1, and "pop" V2 off when the stop button is pressed, so that the original V1 is the top of the stack.

From what I have read, I need a separate view controller for V2.  From the limited information I could find, I need V1's view controller to conform to V2's protocol, V2delegate.  This is what I have, but it is not working:

**ViewController1 with V1**

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, FormViewControllerDelegate {

    let form = FormViewController()

    func addTapped() {
        form.delegate = self
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: form)

        navigationController?.present(nav, animated: true)
    }

    func popForm() {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        navigationController?.popToViewController(self, animated: true)
        print("popped")
    }
}
```

[image]

**ViewController2 with V2**

```
class FormViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: FormViewControllerDelegate?

    func stopTapped() {
        print("pop it")
        delegate?.popForm()
    }
}

protocol FormViewControllerDelegate {
    func popForm()
}
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your VC2, Change to use this code

```
func stopTapped() {
    print("pop it")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this in ViewController1 to present FormViewController

```
func addTapped() {
   let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: form) 
   self.present(nav, animated: true)
}
```

Within FormViewController when want to dismiss use this

```
func stopTapped() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have presented the `ViewController` not pushed the `ViewController`, so what you need is to `dismiss` the Controller instead of `pop` the controller from navigation stack.

```
func popForm() {
    navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true)
    print("popped")
}
```

Better if you renamed the method name to `dissmissForm` instead of `popForm`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dismiss VC2 instead of pop. in self class as below :

```
func stopTapped() {
             self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { _ in })
    }
```

Comment: @defoification why other answer is accepted while i posted before that ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are presenting any viewcontroller then you must use dismissViewController method to remove presented view controller.  popViewController is used when you hqve push any viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `present` then you have to use `dismiss` to remove that currently presented class in stack, when you `dismiss` it, your just next previous class will be in top of the stack. Thats all.. hope, it may helps you.

Answer (score 1):

for pop a `UIViewController` you nee to push and not present. If you need to present a `UIViewVontroller` then on click on "X" you need to dismiss that viewController.

For push view controller

```
func addTapped() {
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(from, animated: true)
    }

func stopTapped() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

For presenting a view controller

```
func addTapped() {
       self.present(from, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

func stopTapped() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

You don't need to code for any protocol to push or present a `UIViewController`